# Locking Row for Access in Presto SQL, udw in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, data-warehouse, presto, presto-jdbc

Hi I'm trying to access teradata tables using Presto SQL and I get a Locking error. I can't use Locking Row for access in Presto SQL because it doesn't support it. So why is there a locking error in first place?
[image]

Comment: please add your sql to your post as text, not an image.

Comment: It's a huge SQL query and confidential information so won't be suitable to post here I suppose

Comment: Nothing in the screenshot indicates a "locking error", just a generic "something went wrong" type message. It says you need to look at the details in the exception chain to find the actual cause.